# How to upload caption file in kaltura?

Tags: javascript, node.js, kaltura

I am trying to upload captions for media entry but i am unable to find any api to upload caption file(.srt etc). From kaltura kmc, it is working fine. I tried hard to upload file by using  kaltura developer console using add caption asset api but it creating empty entry just with language name.

I am getting response like

```
Caption Asset info:
Caption Asset ID: 0_23halw4n

Language: English

Size: 0
```

Please help me how to add file on caption asset. i am not getting any helpful documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps are: 1. uploadToken.add 2. captionAsset.add 3. captionAsset.setContent 4. uploadToken.upload